# Is Windows Phone Isolated storage permanent when I close my emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation, isolatedstorage

I am saving something to file in Isolated Storage in my Windows Phone Application?When I close the emulator and I start the application again there is nothing in my Isolated Storage files. I have read that on real device it will work ok.Is there a way to work ok on emulator?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The storage is non volatile on the actual device. It will persist for as long as the user allows it to persist.

The nature of the emulator (it's a simulation of the device running on your computer) means that isolated storage is effectively volatile as you are creating a new instance of the emulator each time you run it.

What do you need to test that requires isolated storage to be persistent? You will need to either keep the emulator running while you perform the test or set up isolated storage when you first initialise the emulator.

Comment: I have saved to file in IS some URLs and if I haven't close the emulator I can see all URLs from the saved file. When I close the emulator and starts it again the file from IS that I have craeted before does not exist and it is created again and the user have to add the urls again

Comment: @vikifor - I would not expect a file you create in the emulators isolated storage to persist between executions of the emulator. In the real system the file *will* persist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool http://wptools.codeplex.com/  to add in files to storage it's simple to use , when you use a device the storage will persist until the app is uninstalled.